# MS Access Reports - Columns Not Showing in Report Correctly

Tags: ms-access, report, multiple-columns

See attached images.  I have no idea why but my data refuses to split into a second column.  Everything I've searched for makes this seem very easy but I must be missing something. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Report Setup]
[image: print preview]

Comment: What kind of view is that second screenshot? Report View or Print Preview?

Comment: It could be your page margins (left-right) that are too large.

Comment: Image looks like PrintPreview. I tested a report with the same column settings and .25 page margins. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: It is print preview - I had read about people having issue with just 'report view' but I'm using access 2016 that defaults to print preview.  It's not margins because I have the same issue when I only make the report 3" wide.  Could it be related to the data set only being ~20 records and setting the detail section to can grow?  Going to experiment with that tomorrow.

Comment: @ChrisZandstra This might seem like a stupid question, but do you actually have enough data to wrap to a second column?  Choosing "Down, Then Accross" will not form a set balanced columns.  It will not wrap to the second column until the first is full on a page.  Your description nor the preview indicate that how many pages your report generates, etc.

Comment: @ChrisZandstra  Also, I don't follow how making the report 3" indicates anything about the margins.  Shrinking the report width is a separate issue from the margins.  Can you say "It's not the margins because I checked the margins and they are only 0.5 inches on all side" or something similar?

Comment: @CPerkins Honestly I think you're correct that it's just not enough data to fill a page.  I'm trying to get it to fill in a half page section at the top of the page and then I have other data that I would put into the report footer at the bottom of the page.  Not sure if this is doable with columns

Comment: @CPerkins I checked the margins - they're set to narrow (0.25" on all sides)

Comment: Just test it.  It shouldn't take much longer than typing a comment here.  Just resize the footer to be rather high and place a couple dummy items on there and click print preview.  You should see the footer take a bunch of space and force the columns to wrap.  But that's not the only option.  If it still doesn't look and/or behave like you imagine, you might need to create a master report with subreports... one subreport with columns and the other subreport for the single-column portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was basically as posted above - I assumed that the data would split itself into two columns regardless of how much data was present, but really it needed to reach the end of the page before it would split into a second column.  I ended up writing an SQL statement to split up the rows into two columns to meet my needs here.  Thanks for the help.